# iptables on desktop

Tags: iptables

I have some iptables rules and a policy that I want to apply to my desktop. Where is the the configuration file that will make these changes permanent?

Is there any issues with using iptables and NetworkManager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetworkManager has nothing to do with iptables, although you may run into issues if you're using other firewalling software like `ufw`. The default ruleset that is applied by `iptables-apply` is `/etc/network/iptables`, so let's use that one.

The rules file looks like:

```
*FILTER

# filter rules here, example below:

# Reject incoming packets by default
:INPUT REJECT

# example of established packets: you request askubuntu.com and a response is
# send back to TCP port 80
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# Allow traffic to the loopback adapter ("localhost")
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

COMMIT
```

Note that a newline after `COMMIT` is mandatory, without it the file won't load correctly. If you wish to see your current ruleset, run `sudo iptables-save` to output the rules to standard output.

Now create the executable `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables` file to load the rules on startup:

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/network/iptables
```

Do note that if you apply rules during a session (read: before the machine is shutdown/ rebooted), these will be lost on shutdown. If you wish to keep such rules, create another script for saving the rules. Note that comments and such are lost.

`/etc/network/if-pre-down.d`:

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/iptables-save > /etc/network/iptables
```

Comment: ... We need to manually make the iptables read the rules at startup...? Quiet different from RedHat. (Attended some sysadmin courses for RHCE). What about policy, how do we implement those?

Comment: IIRC RH reads the rules within an initscript too (`/etc/init.d/iptables`) and so does ufw (`/etc/init/ufw.conf`). Using `iptables-restore` (or `iptables-apply` when testing rules over SSH) is recommended over setting rules manually with the `iptables` command because if one rule fails to load, none will be loaded and thus preventing possibly locking yourself out. What do you mean by policy? `/etc/network/iptables` is the way to go for IPv4 rules for iptables, `/etc/network/ip6tables` for IPv6.

Comment: Policy is the default firewall behavior, similar to the `:UNPUT REJCT` line. If you issue `iptables -L`, you'll see that `Chain *` has `(policy ACCEPT)` on the left.

Comment: By the way, if I learned anything right in the course, all the packets will be rejected before being allowed to got `lo` in your example. The packets are filtered by the topmost rules first, only moves down, if the earlier rule did not filter it.

Comment: Oh I thought you're referring to policy as in "a paper". The policy rule kicks in after processing the normal rules. Since I've not put `-A INPUT -j REJECT` before the rule allowing `lo` , loopback traffic is still allowed. If you're making a new connection via `lo`, the second rule is used. Otherwise, the first allows the traffic to pass.

Comment: Ah, so `:INPUT REJECT` is the policy. Thanks!